# how to set a threadname in MacOSX

Tags: c++, xcode, multithreading, gdb

In Windows, it is possible to set the threadname via [this code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcb2z8hs.aspx). The threadname is then shown in debuggers.

In MacOSX, I have seen several hints which indicates that there are threadnames. I think the class NSThread also has a name-attribute. My goal is that I can set the threadname in my C++ application and see it in Xcode/gdb.

---

Other related questions:

- [Can I set the name of a thread in pthreads / linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369738/can-i-set-the-name-of-a-thread-in-pthreads-linux) (with a very good answer/overview for pthread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7989973/133374))
- [How to name a thread in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778085/how-to-name-a-thread-in-linux)
- [How to set name to a Win32 Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905876/how-to-set-name-to-a-win32-thread) (also interesting is [this discussion by Bruce Dawson](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2015/10/26/thread-naming-in-windows-time-for-something-better/))
- [(Android) How to set name to the thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457690/how-to-set-name-to-the-thread)

Comment: Can I just ask why you accepted the answer you did - it doesn't answer your question but there are others that do?

Comment: @deanWombourne: At the time of writing, I didn't had MacOSX 10.6. And there were thread names, so the other answer didn't answered that for me. But yea, now this issue is probably outdated.

Comment: Handy for people who are trying to build stuff for Leopard, though!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I recommend the following:

```
[[NSThread currentThread] setName:@"My thread name"]; // For Cocoa  
pthread_setname_np("My thread name"); // For GDB.
```

(You'll need to include pthread.h)
Works a treat in XCode 3.2.3 (at least for iPhone development)

Comment: Meaning no offense to cdespinosa (hi Chris! :), it seems odd to me that his non-answer was accepted.  DaveH actually answered the question (and I was able to use his supplied answer to solve MY problem +1 :)

Comment: Yes, I agree. This sounds like a much better answer. Makes more sense

Comment: Btw., `pthread_setname_np` is also available on many other platforms. However, the interface is usually different. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7989973/133374) for a good overview.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Xcode are you using? Thread names are only supported in Mac OS X 10.6 and Xcode 3.2.

Comment: I am using OSX 10.5 and Xcode 3.1.4. So no chance there? No chance at all in OSX 10.5? In the doc for NSThread:setName, it says available in Mac OS X v10.5 and later.

Comment: Yes, but the threadname is not propagated from the Objective-C layer to the runtime threads layer in 10.5, because the pthread_setname_np API doesn't exist until 10.6, and you need Xcode 3.2 to fetch and display the thread name.

Comment: So, Xcode 3.2 on MacOSX 10.5 would be able to display thread names if I propagate the threadnames to the runtime threads layer? How can I do that?

Comment: No, Xcode 3.2 is 10.6 only.  If you want to see thread names in the Xcode UI, you have to use Xcode 3.2 on Mac OS X 10.6.

Comment: Just want to say this explicitely for other readers: pthread_setname_np is the solution.