# gdb how to get thread name displayed

Tags: c, linux, gdb, pthreads

There are many threads created in my application. some of the threads name are visible in the gdb while i execute the command 'info threads', others are not displayed. How to get all the thread name itself instead of the hex value like 0xb7fe1424

```
4 Thread 0xb68ffb70 (LWP 18377)  0xb7fe1424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
* 3 Thread 0xb7291b70 (LWP 18375)  JKMainT (arg=0x0) at mylib.cpp:482
2 Thread 0xb7a92b70 (LWP 18374)  0xb7fe1424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
1 Thread 0xb7a94730 (LWP 18371)  0xb7fe1424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
```

Comment: To add more.. I put break point at mylib.cpp:482, and down the line it creates a thread.

Comment: That is not the thread name, that is the name of the function which that thread is currently executing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you upgrade to gdb 7.3 or later, "info thread" will show thread names; at least on native (not remote) Linux.

Answer (score 9):

You can set the thread name via non-standard POSIX api calls. GDB (and other debuggers) will display these names.

On Linux

```
// watch out, 16 char limit on the name
pthread_setname_np(pthread_self(), "My thread name");
```

On Mac

```
pthread_setname_np("My thread name");
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369738/can-i-set-the-name-of-a-thread-in-pthreads-linux

Answer (score 8):

Threads don't have names by default - the `JKMainT` string there is the name of the current function.

Try selecting one of the threads and viewing the backtrace - that might give you a good idea which thread it is. Otherwise, you could try [prctl](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/prctl.2.html) with `PR_SET_NAME` if it's available.

Comment: an easier way to do this is pthread_setname_np(pthread_t *, const char*)

Answer (score 0):

- (gdb) info threads  - will display all the threads
- (gdb) thread  will switch to the thread you selected and
  display the thread name
- (gdb) thread  - will display current thread name

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).