# 'pthread_setname_np' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

I have created multiple threads in my application. I want to assign a name to each pthread so I used `pthread_setname_np` which worked on Ubuntu but is not working on SUSE Linux.

I googled it and came to know '_np' means 'non portable' and this api is not available on all OS flavors of Linux.

So now I want to do it only if the API is available. How to determine whether the api is available or not ? I need something like this.

```
#ifdef SOME_MACRO
    pthread_setname_np(tid, "someName");
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the feature_test_macro `_GNU_SOURCE` to check if this function might be available:

```
#ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
    pthread_setname_np(tid, "someName");
#endif
```

But the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html) states that the `pthread_setname_np` and `pthread_getname_np` are introduced in `glibc 2.12`. So if you are using an older glibc (say 2.5) then defining `_GNU_SOURCE` will not help.

So it's best to avoid these non portable function and you can easily *name* the threads yourself as part of your thread creation, for example, using a map between thread ID and a array such as:

```
pthread_t tid[128];
char thr_names[128][256]; //each name corresponds to on thread in 'tid'
```

You can check the glibc version using:

```
getconf GNU_LIBC_VERSION
```

Comment: I am using glibc 2.11.1, so the macro is not working for me.. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Isn't `_GNU_SOURCE` a macro you're meant to **set** to use GNU-specific APIs, rather than **read** to test for presence of GNU-specific APIs?

Comment: @CraigMcQueen You're absolutely right. I probably meant, define it to get the GNU specific API and then suggested to *not* use them. Your concern about being variants...I don't see any other way than to check for implementation specific macros. I personally would do what I suggested (name them myself) rather cluttering with ifdefs (but I must admit I never had a situation in which I need to name them in the few pthreads applications I wrote).

Answer (score 3):

Since this function was introduced in glibc 2.12, you could use:

```
#if ((__GLIBC__ > 2) || ((__GLIBC__ == 2) && (__GLIBC_MINOR__ >= 12)))
    pthread_setname_np(tid, "someName");
#endif
```

Comment: Your answer was helpful, if wrong in part. The preprocessor expression should be:

`#if (2 < __GLIBC__) ||  ((2 == __GLIBC__) && (12 <= __GLIBC_MINOR__))`

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing - finding out if a particular function exists in your compilation environment - is what people use [GNU Autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/autoconf.html) scripts for.

If your project is already using autoconf, you can add this to your configure source, after the point where you have checked for the pthreads compiler and linker flags:

```
AC_CHECK_FUNCS(pthread_setname_np)
```

...and it will define a macro HAVE_PTHREAD_SETNAME_NP if the function exists.

Comment: The problem with that is, different platforms have different parameters for the same function name `pthread_setname_np()`. So it's not enough just to test for the presence of the function. See [Can I set the name of a thread in pthreads/Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7989973/60075)

Comment: Yes, you can use `AC_COMPILE_IFELSE()` instead to test which variant of `pthread_setname_np()` you have.

Comment: I've just tried the above AC_CHECK_FUNCS() and it doesn't seem to work on a system with glibc-2.19 (Ubuntu 14.04), although I can compile code using the function just fine:

`checking for pthread_setname_np... no`

Maybe some extra kludge-o-magic is necessary because _GNU_SOURCE needs to be defined?

Comment: @fencekicker: Yes, if you want `_GNU_SOURCE` in an autoconf project you should use the `AC_GNU_SOURCE` macro early in configure, before the compiler is invoked.  You won't need to manually define it yourself then, either.