# Python thread name doesn't show up on ps or htop

Tags: python, multithreading, htop

When I set the name for a Python thread, it doesn't show up on htop or ps. The ps output only shows `python` as the thread name. Is there any way to set a thread name so that it shows up on system reports like them?

```
from threading import Thread
import time


def sleeper():
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        print "sleeping"

t = Thread(target=sleeper, name="Sleeper01")
t.start()
t.join()
```

`ps -T -p {PID}` output

```
  PID  SPID TTY          TIME CMD
31420 31420 pts/30   00:00:00 python
31420 31421 pts/30   00:00:00 python
```

Comment: This is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369738/can-i-set-the-name-of-a-thread-in-pthreads-linux) I think

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood: Not really, this question isn't about C, it's about Python.

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood Thanks Nick! I'm reading up on pthreads right now. Yes this helps, but it still doesn't answer my question when it comes to Python (or am I missing something?)

Comment: What happens if you launch a new process instead of a thread?

Comment: @VincentSavard my bad, you are right!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First install the [prctl module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-prctl).  (On debian/ubuntu just type `sudo apt-get install python-prctl`)

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import prctl

def sleeper():
    prctl.set_name("sleeping tiger")
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        print "sleeping"

t = Thread(target=sleeper, name="Sleeper01")
t.start()
t.join()
```

This prints

```
$ ps -T
  PID  SPID TTY          TIME CMD
22684 22684 pts/29   00:00:00 bash
23302 23302 pts/29   00:00:00 python
23302 23303 pts/29   00:00:00 sleeping tiger
23304 23304 pts/29   00:00:00 ps
```

Note: python3 users may wish to use [pyprctl](https://pyprctl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#module-pyprctl).

Comment: Thanks @NickCraig-Wood! Why doesn't Python straightaway pass the given name in to prctl when creating threads from Thread class?

Comment: Don't install prctl with `pip` or you get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_name'`.

Comment: @BurnsBA you need `pip install python-prctl` to get this functionality.  The pip module named `prctl` does not have the `set_name` function.

Comment: on my linux mint 18.1 (ubuntu) install, I had to use ```ps -eT``` to see the thread name.

Comment: debian currently lacks a python3-prctl so I had to `pip3 install python-prct` as JohnTESlade suggested.  also it needs `apt install libcap-dev` before.

Comment: …but it didn't change the process name as seen on `top` or `ps`.  then I tried `setproctitle` from pip and that one worked.

Comment: So what is the relationship to python's threading API's `name` property? what good is name="Sleeper01" here?

Comment: In my short experience, this approach may mangle thread names if not used right across different threads, as each thread essentially overwrites the name in a global way.

Comment: When using top, launch it in 'thread mode'  to see the individual thread-names: `top -H`

Answer (score 12):

Prctl module is nice and provide many features, but depends libcap-dev package. Libcap2 is most likely installed because it is a dependency of many packages (systemd for example). So if you only need set thread name, use libcap2 over ctypes.

See improved Grief answer below.

```
LIB = 'libcap.so.2'
try:
    libcap = ctypes.CDLL(LIB)
except OSError:
    print(
        'Library {} not found. Unable to set thread name.'.format(LIB)
    )
else:
    def _name_hack(self):
        # PR_SET_NAME = 15
        libcap.prctl(15, self.name.encode())
        threading.Thread._bootstrap_original(self)

    threading.Thread._bootstrap_original = threading.Thread._bootstrap
    threading.Thread._bootstrap = _name_hack
```

Comment: This worked for me, be sure to use `ps -T` when checking if it worked. Also, for Ubuntu at least, the character limit for thread names is 15 so keep it below that if you're using the names in a grep kind of case.

Answer (score 8):

On Python 2, I use the following monkey patch to propagate the Thread's name to the system if `prctl` is installed in the system:

```
try:
    import prctl
    def set_thread_name(name): prctl.set_name(name)

    def _thread_name_hack(self):
        set_thread_name(self.name)
        threading.Thread.__bootstrap_original__(self)

    threading.Thread.__bootstrap_original__ = threading.Thread._Thread__bootstrap
    threading.Thread._Thread__bootstrap = _thread_name_hack
except ImportError:
    log('WARN: prctl module is not installed. You will not be able to see thread names')
    def set_thread_name(name): pass
```

After the execution of this code, you can set thread's name as usual:

```
threading.Thread(target=some_target, name='Change monitor', ...)
```

That means, that if you already set names for threads, you don't need to change anything. I cannot guarantee, that this is 100% safe, but it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was confused after I found a tool--**py-spy** to show python thread while running.

install: pip3 install -i https://pypi.doubanio.com/simple/ py-spy

usage: py-spy dump --pid process-number

for example, py-spy dump --pid 1234 can show all the thread stacks,name,id of python process 1234

Answer (score 1):

https://pypi.org/project/namedthreads/ provides a way to patch `threading.Thread.start` to call `pthread_setname_np` with the Python `Thread.name`.

It is compatible with Python 2.7 & 3.4+ (I've tested it with 3.10)

To activate it,

```
import namedthreads
namedthreads.patch()
```

Note that thread names in Python are unlimited, but pthreads has a limit of 15 char, so the Python name will be trimmed.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution (actually a dirty one, since it sets the process name, not the thread name) is to use the `setproctitle` module from pypi.

You can install it with `pip install setproctitle` and use it as follow:

```
import setproctitle
import threading
import time

def a_loop():
    setproctitle.setproctitle(threading.currentThread().name)
    # you can otherwise explicitly declare the name:
    # setproctitle.setproctitle("A loop")
    while True:
        print("Looping")
        time.sleep(99)

t = threading.Thread(target=a_loop, name="ExampleLoopThread")
t.start()
```

Comment: While still useful, this answer is not correct. It sets the process title, not the thread title

Comment: @Wolph: thanks for the comment, I've inserted it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to follow answers here to install `python-prctl` or `pyprctl`. However none of them could be installed because the need for a `gcc` that we don't have.

After some digging on the net, this python issue 15500 gave a nice solution [[https://bugs.python.org/issue15500]](https://bugs.python.org/issue15500). Here is what I've got based on it:

```
import ctypes, os, threading
def set_thread_name_np(the_name):
    the_lib_path = "/lib/libpthread-2.42.so"
    if not os.path.isfile(the_lib_path):
        return None
    try:
        libpthread = ctypes.CDLL(the_lib_path)
    except:
        return None
    if hasattr(libpthread, "pthread_setname_np"):
        pthread_setname_np = libpthread.pthread_setname_np
        pthread_setname_np.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p,
                                       ctypes.c_char_p]
        pthread_setname_np.restype = ctypes.c_int
        if isinstance(the_name, str):
            the_name = the_name.encode('ascii', 'replace')
        if type(the_name) is not bytes:
            return None
        the_thread = threading.current_thread()
        ident = getattr(the_thread, "ident", None)
        if ident is not None:
            pthread_setname_np(ident, the_name[:15])
            return True
    return None
```