# Is there a way to set title/name of a thread in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, linux-kernel, python-multithreading

I would like to set the title of a thread (the title seen in `ps` or `top`)in Python in order to make it visible to process tracer programs. All the threads of a process are always called `python` or called file name when `/usr/bin/python` is used and the script is called via ./script.

Now, I want to change each thread's name. I have a simple script with 4 threads (incl main thread). I use `threading` to start the threads.

Is there a way that I could achieve this without having to install third-party stuff? Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: That solved the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
def your_function(arg1, arg2, argn):
    * do stuff *


new_thread = threading.Thread(target=your_function, args=(arg1, arg2, argn))
new_thread.name = 'your name'
new.thread.start()
```

Where `new_thread.name` is your answer.

Comment: Trying to reconcile with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361035/python-thread-name-doesnt-show-up-on-ps-or-htop

Answer (score 2):

Just do the following:
`t = threading.Thread(name='my_thread')`

Comment: Nope, that didn't work, check the link in the comments, pactl must be used in order to register the name to linux process list.

Comment: You probably mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361035/python-thread-name-doesnt-show-up-on-ps-or-htop)

Comment: Why the above answer has 17 likes where as this has -2 ? Even though both answers didnt address the actual question