# How to change a python thread name from inside the thread on Windows?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a main thread that gets connections and immediately spawns new threads then inside the thread it receives a name that gets logged, currently my threads are named Thread-n. I would like to change the name of the thread from inside. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361035/python-thread-name-doesnt-show-up-on-ps-or-htop), but it sadly only works on linux, any similar program to do this on Windows?

Answer (score 14):

One can do this by using:

```
import threading
threading.current_thread().name = "my_name"
```