# All threads in my python application appear as "python3"

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I am creating a GUI multithreading application with Python3. After a while playing with it is starting to go slower and slower and the number of threads is increasing a lot.

I am using htop to see the number of threads and also the name, but all of them appear as "python3" so I can not distinguish them.

I have something like:

```
myapp
  |_ python3
  |_ python3
  |_ python3
  ...
```

I am creating the threads in this way:

```
recorder = Thread(target=self.record, name='recorder')
recorder.start()
requester = Thread(target=self.run, name='requester')
requester.start()
```

So in the tree view of htop I spected to see something like:

```
myapp
  |_ recorder
  |_ requester
  ...
```

Should I create the threads in a different way? What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps show snippets of what is `self.record` and `self.run`?

Comment: @Axios I don't think that would help

Comment: @Axois it is just the thread code. The recorder is writing data in a csv file and the run method is reading from a socket. Is it important?

Comment: Your way of calling of calling threads seems fine. However I would suggest to `.join()` the threads after calling `.start()` which is a good idea if your threads arent daemon. However for the slowing part, im suspecting its due to the operations of your functions, but @PeterWood thinks otherwise, so I'm not sure either :).

Comment: Check out this existing answer: [Python thread name doesn't show up on ps or htop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361035/python-thread-name-doesnt-show-up-on-ps-or-htop)