# Can you change a thread's name from within itself in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369738/how-to-set-the-name-of-a-thread-in-linux-pthreads) I can see that this is at least possible for MacOS.

I thought maybe this would do it:

```
pthread_setname_np(pthread_self(), "NEW_NAME");
```

This does not work as `pthread_self()` returns thread ID and not a `pthread_t` data type. I could not find a function that would return current thread `pthread_t`, a one that would allow to convert thread ID to `pthread_t` nor a one that would allow to set the current name without needing to provide the `pthread_t` data type as one of the arguments. Thanks.

Comment: You name your threads??

Comment: The `_np` suffix indicates ‘non-portable’.

Comment: @MartinJames It's for error logging.

Comment: `pthread_self()` *does* return a `pthread_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, [`pthread_self()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_self.3.html) should already return a `pthread_t`, according to the pthread documentation, so the code you show seems correct. In any case, I would avoid using `pthread_setname_np()` since as the name implies it's non-portable.

The standard way to do this in Linux is through [`prctl(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html):

> ```
> #include <sys/prctl.h>
>
> int prctl(int option, unsigned long arg2, unsigned long arg3,
>             unsigned long arg4, unsigned long arg5);
> ```
>
> ```
> PR_SET_NAME (since Linux 2.6.9)
>        Set the name of the calling thread, using the value in the
>        location pointed to by (char *) arg2.  The name can be up to
>        16 bytes long, including the terminating null byte.  (If the
>        length of the string, including the terminating null byte,
>        exceeds 16 bytes, the string is silently truncated.)  This is
>        the same attribute that can be set via pthread_setname_np(3)
>        and retrieved using pthread_getname_np(3).  The attribute is
>        likewise accessible via /proc/self/task/[tid]/comm, where tid
>        is the name of the calling thread.
> ```

You just need to call `prctl()` with `PR_SET_NAME` as first argument and the name you want to set as second:

```
prctl(PR_SET_NAME, "name_here", 0, 0, 0);
```

Note that, as the manual states, the name cannot exceed 16 bytes (terminator included).

Comment: `prctl` is also non-portable, not available on windows/mingw, osx, bsd, and is not available on msvc. You should detect the correct API for this via your build configure process at compile time, and set flags to determine which to use, covering `prctl`, `pthread_setname_np` and `SetThreadDescription` depending upon availability.

Comment: @braindigitalis all true, OP tagged the question with [Linux] though.