# XCode Instruments: name threads

Tags: pthreads, xcode-instruments

For profiling multithreaded applications, it would be very useful to me to set a name for each thread.

Initial googling turns up pthread_setname_np() ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369738/can-i-set-the-name-of-a-thread-in-pthreads-linux)), but when used, it doesn't appear to show up in Instruments.

Is there a way to do this from a C application?

Comment: Very good question. I would like to know the answer too. A similar question was handled here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057960/how-to-set-a-threadname-in-macosx

Comment: So `https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsthread/1414122-name` won't be enough for you?

Comment: Are you restricted to Xcode specifically? Also, for pure C applications this is in fact a thing. There is fancy software that does this.