# How to set name to the thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, debugging

Is there a way to set a friendly name to a thread in code?

For example, I want the thread with name Thread-11 on the image was named something like 'MyImportThread'.

[image: example-threads]

Comment: yep.. it was a very dumb question, but I was confused a little of how to do it... :) thx for the answers, I even do not know which of them chose as correct :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can easily pass a thread name in Its **Constructor**, like:

`Thread foo = new Thread("Foo");`

... or by calling `Thread#setName`:

> public final void setName (String threadName)

Sets the name of the Thread.

as `thread.setName("Thread-11");` or like `Thread.currentThread().setName("Thread-11");`

Answer (score 8):

Check the [`Thread` constructors](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#pubctors), there are a few with a `String name` parameter. Or you can call `setName(String)` on an existing Thread.

Answer (score 7):

Did you try something like this?

```
Thread.currentThread().setName("MyThread");
```

Have look also at [`Threads reference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) especially at constructors.

Answer (score 3):

The class [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setName%28java.lang.String%29) has a method for that:

```
public final void setName (String threadName)

Since: API Level 1
Sets the name of the Thread.
```

Did you try it?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread("MyImportThread") {
      public void run(){    
        // code
      }
   };
   thread.start();
   System.out.println(thread.getName());
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set a name to thread using:

```
Thread.getCurrentThread().setName(threadName);
```