# C++11 thread id, Is there a easier naming convention?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread

Having an easy naming convention can help with complex tasks and debugging large programs.

Is it possible to have a better naming convention than

```
0x115f57000
0x115fda000
0x11605d000
0x1160e0000
```

For instance exception thrown on thread id 0x1035a8000! might not help much. It also does not help that the thread id will change every-time the program is run.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Give a name to a boost thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342159/give-a-name-to-a-boost-thread) - I know you're asking about C++11, but std::thread and boost::thread are very similar and the techniques for naming threads are more about the platform (Windows vs. Linux) since there's no cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can always stop you program at start where threads are created, look in the debugger which thread does what, and take a note.