# Any Windows tool to show details of running threads?

Tags: windows, multithreading, process

I'm trying to find a tool similar to the Windows Task Manager utility which can show details on all threads running in a given process, such as their names, IDs, etc ..

Windows Task Manager only lists the number of threads running in a given process .. It doesn't give any thread specific information ..

Comment: Open windows task manager select view -> select columns to add more details such as PID (process ID),  etc

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using [Process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). It's much more powerful than task manager and should suit your needs.

Comment: if i have thread in asp.net  website ..How i can see the thread using  process explorer  ex:OrderStatusFromThread.IsBackground = true;
        OrderStatusFromThread.Name = "OrderStatusFromThread";
        OrderStatusFromThread.Start();

Comment: You can see different process on the list. When you hover you see the exe. args as well. But for threads you just need to `double click on a process and go to Threads tab`. Multiprocess application and multithread application are different. I coded a concurrent application which prints executing thread number on the screen and I can see my threads on this app.

Comment: @MohamadMahmoud For Asp.NET ,if you use asp.net IIS uses `thread pool` and manages threads innerly. You do not need to show an extra effort for managing threads. Thus it's not recommended using Application object because it's shared and cause many locks. We use session objects for different users which also use locks as well but without locking Application object and using a lock for a particular client.This means better performance for web apps.

Comment: doesn't seem to include the thread name....

Answer (score 10):

You can also try [processHacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) which is free, Open source and mature.It has more option than ProcessExplorer.

Comment: This one works out of the box on Win 10 compared to ProcessExplorer which needs the Debugging tools. Great!

Comment: This one worked for me also on windows 7, process Explorer pops error message (Missing function: winsta!WinStationConnectW),.....

processHacker worked perfectly with no problem, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Symantec Endpoint Protection mentions this tool not to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

## THREAD DETAILS

As *darioo* has already commented, applications like *Process Explorer* from Microsoft (previously: *System Internals*) can provide additional information about an application's threads:

- ThreadId
- Kernel Time
- User Time
- Starting address
- Current State
- Context Switches
- etc.

*Process Explorer* can be downloaded for **free** from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

## THREAD NAME

The original question also inquired about determining a thread's name.

It is my understanding that the Windows operating system does not support the concept of a thread having a name.  This concept only exists within the *Visual Studio* development environment.

If this is true, then another option to get a thread's name at run-time is print it out along with your debug/log messages.  At the very least, you can use this approach to keep track of thread lifetime.  For example:

```
2015/06/02 14:22:17 CoreEngine Quality Assurance thread is initializing... ThreadId=123
2015/06/02 14:22:17 CoreEngine Quality Assurance thread has initialized successfully. ThreadId=123
...
2015/06/02 16:68:17 CoreEngine Quality Assurance thread is terminating... ThreadId=123
2015/06/02 16:68:18 CoreEngine Quality Assurance thread has terminated successfully. ThreadId=123
```

## Additional References #

- [How to set name to a Win32 Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905876/how-to-set-name-to-a-win32-thread)
- [How to: Set a Thread Name in Native Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcb2z8hs.aspx)
- [How to: Set a Thread Name in Managed Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/581hfskb.aspx)

Comment: You can get a .NET thread name with WinDbg, and boy is it fun! http://stackoverflow.com/a/31573736/313445