# Can Windbg display thread names?

Tags: .net, windows, debugging, windbg

[Windbg should understand](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.windbg/2atvu7h3D3c) the [MS exception protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcb2z8hs.aspx) used to pass thread names to a debugger.

I can't get this to work. Looking on the net there are many examples showing "~" thread lists with no thread names, and that's what I see. I'm debugging a .NET x86 process, and I've tried the WDK 8.1 x86 and x64 versions of Windbg.

Does anyone know if this feature is still available? What am I missing?

Comment: I'm using WinDbg since 2010 and I've never seen thread names like that

Comment: The post is from 2005, so you might try with WinDbg 6.4.0007.0 (find it in [Windows 2003 SDK](http://download.cnet.com/Windows-Server-2003-R2-Platform-SDK-ISO-Download/3000-10248_4-10731094.html))

Comment: Tangentially, [2018 might be the year](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2018-roadmap) .NET supports [a new thread naming mechanism](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/17608120-properly-support-native-thread-naming-via-the-sett).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For .NET threads, the following works for "normal" `Thread`s (manually created threads, since I don't know a way to name threadpool threads):

A `Thread` is a class and thus can be found in the .NET managed heap:

```
0:000>.loadby sos clr
0:000> !dumpheap -stat -type Thread
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
...
725e4960       11          572 System.Threading.Thread
```

Note that there is other output as well, since `!dumpheap` looks for parts of class names. The Method Table (MT) however, identifies a class uniquely, so that's what we use from now on:

```
0:000> !dumpheap -short -mt 725e4960
023123d0
02312464
02313c80
...
```

These are the addresses of `Thread` objects. Since it is clean output, we can use it in a loop:

```
0:000> .foreach (address {!dumpheap -short -mt 725e4960}) {.echo ${address} }
023123d0
02312464
02313c80    
...
```

Inside the loop, we can use the address to get more information about the thread. First, let's find out how a Thread looks like internally:

```
0:000> !do 023123d0
Name:        System.Threading.Thread
...
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
...
725e3e18  400076e        c        System.String  0 instance 02313c0c m_Name
...
```

At offset `+0xC` (depending on the bitness!), there's the `m_Name` member. That's a string. Let's find out how a string looks like:

```
0:000> !do poi(023123d0+c)
Name:        System.String
...
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
...
725e4810  40000ac        8          System.Char  1 instance       4d m_firstChar
```

So, the first character of the string is at offset `+0x08`. Strings in .NET are Unicode, so we can view it with `du`:

```
0:000> du poi(023123d0+c)+8
02313c14  "My named thread 0"
```

Combine all this knowledge into a single command:

```
.foreach (address {!dumpheap -short -mt 725e4960})
{
    du poi(${address}+c)+8
}
```

(formatted for readability, put it all in one line)

If you try that, you'll find that it may output something like

```
00000008  "????????????????????????????????"
```

This happens when `m_Name` is `null`. If you care about that, you can add a check for null:

```
.foreach (address {!dumpheap -short -mt 725e4960})
{
    .if (poi(${address}+c) != 0) {
        du poi(${address}+c)+8
    }
}
```

(formatted for readability, put it all in one line)

Other improvements:

- do the same for the thread ID
- prettify output (use `.printf` instead of `dd` and `du`)

Final result:

```
.foreach (address {!dumpheap -short -mt 725e4960}) 
{
    .if (poi(${address}+c) != 0) 
    {
        .printf "%d ",poi(${address}+28);
        .printf "%mu\r\n", poi(${address}+c)+8
    }
}
```

Comment: Thread pool threads are no different from regular threads, but naming them is usually pointless since they are reused.

Comment: It seems .NET doesn't use the first-chance exception protocol for thread names, though I haven't had time to verify that. Thanks for the tutorial. I've added your script to my rarely-used WinDbg cheat sheet!

Comment: I'm now working at a firm where I'm doing .Net development. I have just used the `.foreach` loop and it is working fine. I just have one question: the number `725e4960` obviously will change for every application. Is there a way to get this inside a function, something like `.foreach ... (!dumpheap -sort -mt $((get_ID(System.Threading.Thread)))`? (I know, I'm mixing Windbg with bash calculation notation and it looks ugly)

Comment: @Dominique: I think this would make up it's own good question. You can assign a pseudo register `.foreach /pS 7 /ps 4 (token  {!name2ee mscorlib.dll System.Threading.Thread}) { r $t0 = ${token}}` and you can then use it like `!dumpheap -short -mt $t0`

Comment: @thomasweller this is nicely detailed!  it works for me up to the point where I'm using the `!do poi(...)` command - I get an error saying `Invalid parameter poi(000002245c304028+18)` (for me the m_name is at offset 18).  I'm using a fairly recent version of WinDbg (1.2303.30001.0).  Is there any help you can provide?

Comment: @MichaelBray please check if it is 0n18 (decimal) or 0x18 (hex)

Comment: @thomasweller it's 18 hex, because some of the other offsets listed are hex values.  However even if it was decimal, using `poi(000002245c304028+12)` doesn't work either, nor does `poi(000002245c304028+24)` nor `poi(000002245c304040)`.

Comment: @MichaelBray: sorry, at the moment I have no other idea. Feel free to ask a new question. Reference this answer, and explain that it is not a duplicate. Be specific about your versions. There are differences from .NET Framework to .NET Core. Ideally, provide a [mre], even if it's just trivial 5 lines of code. I'm getting tired doing  that myself. If you like, leave me a link to the question and I'll gladly upvote it, if it is fine.